# Duda con X-binoacci en C++

Tags: c++, estructuras, fibonacci

Necesito crear una función **recursiva** en C++ que me permita resolver cada tipo de sucesión, es decir, fibonacci, tribonacci, etcétera. El problema es que no sé cómo implementar la función para 'n' tipos, ya que en cada uno el **return** debe ser diferente, en Fibonacci debe ser **return Fib(n-1)+Fib(n-2)** y en Tribonacci debe ser **return Fib(n-1)+Fib(n-2)+Fib(n-3)**. ¿Algún consejo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para eso tienes a tu disposición los bucles:

```
int Fib(int n, int paso)
{
  int to_return = 0;

  for( int i=1; i<=paso; i++ )
  {
    to_return += Fib(n-i, paso);
  }

  return to_return;
}
```

Así, si `paso==2`, se ejecutaría la secuencia *Fibonacci*, mientras que con `paso==3` tendrías *Tribonacci* y así.

En cualquier caso la función no está completa y la razón es que mi objetivo no es hacerte los deberes sino responder tu duda.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. Ya tengo una mejor idea de cómo hacerlo, gracias por no hacerme el código. Un saludo.